# How can I achieve a design like this

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I want to achieve something like this

[image]

It opens up a bottom sheet which is something I can do

P.S Also this arrow up changes its direction to arrow down. I also want to know how to achieve that

Comment: You need to use Clip path. I will recommen this package: https://pub.dev/packages/proste_bezier_curve